# Dipping Chalah in honey the first night of Succos?

Tags: halacha, passover, sukkot

The Tur (Orach Chaim 475), argues on the Rambam, who holds that one must dip the Matzah in Charoset, and the Tur not only disagrees with this, but even holds that by doing so, he would not have fulfilled his obligation, because the taste of the Charoset would nullify the taste of the Matzah like it says in the Gemara (Pesachim 115a) that ״מצוות מבטלות זו את זו״

Now it would seem that this issue should apply to any Mitzvah, such as eating in the Sukkah - is it brought down anywhere, that on the first night of succos, one should eat a כזית of bread without honey, or anything else, to be חושש for this reason?

Comment: Unless you are also being strict to not have egg challah on the first night of sukkot (as it's lechem ashirah) then this seems clearly unnecessary

Comment: I don't add meat to my kreplach for the same reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rav Eliyahu Baruch on Sukkos brings gedolim that didn't dip their bread into honey on the first night of Sukkos, the reason being that the honey would nullify the taste of bread (like your gemara). The responsa Yad Eliyahu 23, 1 rules like that as well.

However, achronim (Rav Eliyahu Baruch, Rav Moshe Sternbuch (Moadim V'zmanim)) say it's dependent on what the mitzva is. If it's eating in the sukka, then your logic would apply. But if it's living in the sukka through eating bread, then the taste of bread isn't so relevant.

Comment: What about the egg, sugar, etc. mixed into the challah before it was baked? Why is dipping worse?

Comment: @DoubleAA that's stam a question on the gemara in pesachim, that we see we don't say that, reason by matza you cant mix eggs because it wont be lechem oni. Not because it nullifies the taste.